# Python-shell for Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, buffer, stdin

I am trying to get use a python script within my node.js application
using the NPM package python-shell. I can run the script from command line using this format on Mac OS.

```
python3 myScript.py < input.zip > output.wav
```

However when I try to run the script in my node application I get this error

```
Error: usage: myScript.py [-h] [-s FACTOR]
myScript.py: error: unrecognized arguments: input output
```

I get the same error when I remove the < and > from the command in the terminal I have tried to add the < and > to the python-shell options however I get the same error with the < and > included.

Node.js

```
        const input = `input.zip`;
        const output = `output.wav`;
        const options: any = {
          args: [input,output],
          pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        };


        PythonShell.run('myScript.py', options, function (err, results) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('finished');
          console.log(results);
        });
```

myScript.py

```
def main():
    print("started")
    global args
    args = parse_args()
    write_wav(read_chunks(sys.stdin.buffer), sys.stdout.buffer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am really unsure what to do to get this working any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you are providing a var name as parameter, not its value

In nodejs I would code this :

```
var python_options = {       
  mode: 'text',       
  pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python',
  pythonOptions: ['-u'],
  scriptPath: '/home/pi/njs/proves_js',
  args: ['', '', '']
} ;

python_options.args[0] = "input.zip"
```

and in python this :

```
if len(sys.argv) > 2: szInFN  = str( sys.argv[1] )  # get output.zip
if len(sys.argv) > 1: szOutFN = str( sys.argv[0] )  # get input.zip
```

Good luck